# What is the inflation schedule for EOS private blockchain?

Tags: cleos, block-producer, eosio.token, private-blockchain

I have followed the bios boot sequence https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence to create private EOS blockchain. Now everything has been done but there are some point I want to understand :

1)I don't know what is the inflation schedule and  how block producer will get rewards also how can I check that BP is producing blocks and  getting reward?

2)Is there any command to check BP's reward?

3)I have created a new token named TOKN and issued it to one account and after that I have transferred some part of it to another account. Now I want to understand that BP will get reward in this token or in any other(default is SYS) token?

4) Right now I have not done the resignation process of eosio and system accounts because after that i can get ram issue for creating new account. Will it create any problem for producing blocks?

Please guide me for the same. Thanks in advance.